# How to get angularjs http request url from options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var httpOptions = {
    url: "http://doman/files",
    method: "GET",
    params : {
        type: pdf,
        page: '112',
        country: "USA",
        lang: "en"                    
    }
};

$http(httpOptions).success(function(data){  });
```

I am using angularjs. I have an http options to send server. But I want to get the parsed url after succes like this, because I have a lat of params and not want do manually:

```
http://mydoman/files?type=pdf&page=112&country=USA&lang=en
```

Comment: What kind of parsed url do you mean? Something like this:

http://mydoman/files/pdf/112/USA/en

?

If yes, you can parse on server side and return in data.

Comment: like this htt://mydoman/files?type=pdf&page=112&country=USA&lang=en

Comment: Do you use jQuery for your project?

Comment: just change `type: pdf`, to `type: 'pdf'`,

Comment: I am using angularjs not Jquery

Comment: I mean, do you use jQuery with Angular, or you use jqLite?

Comment: If you use jQuery there is a simple solution, otherwise you are aout of luck.

Comment: After reading the source code it seems, as @dfsq said, you are really out of luck. The `$http` service doesn't exposed the parsed url in anyway, and the `buildUrl()` function that the `$http` use is also private.

Comment: it is interesting for a strong API like Angularjs :(

Comment: Internally Angular uses [`buildUrl`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L981) function to construct url for `$http` calls. This function is not available externally and not exposed as service. So it's not part of the API.

Answer (score 1):

That is so easy to do with `JQuery.param()`. If you have JQuery in your project, you can simply use line below :

```
httpOptions.url + '/?' + $.param(httpOptions.params);
```

And please do not forget to fix the property `type: pdf` to `type: 'pdf'`